# Windows Task Manager Save or Graph a Process

Tags: windows, memory-management, process

I've been monitoring some memory usage by specific processes through Windows Task Manager for awhile and at the moment I've just been taking down a bunch of values into a notepad file.  This seems pretty inefficient and also not nearly as easy to glean information from at a glance.  Plus, it may not necessarily be accurate as with how much the processes change I definitely have missed some information.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a tool that could be used to save process information to a file, or maybe even graph specific process memory usage.  I don't think it would be worth me writing my own script since I have no idea how to access the task manager programmatically, and I feel like something already must be out there like what I'm looking for.  If anyone knows of anything that would be nice.

Comment: Task Manager doesn't report useful memory usage statistics anyway

Comment: @David Well I'm open to suggestions of other tools that may report useful statistics as well.

Comment: I don't know what your goals are; hard to give advice

Comment: @David, in general, to monitor memory usage and have a log of information on it.  Probably in the form of a text file or a graph.

Comment: Memory usage of what processes? And what particular aspect of memory usage? It's a frightfully complex area. What is motivating this?

Comment: @David the Private Working Set of memory.  I'm looking for a memory leak.  I want to monitor sidebar and some other miscellaneous processes.

Comment: that statistic won't find a memory leak. You need a dedicated profiling tool for that. What language? What type of app? How do you know you have a leak?

Comment: @David.  I'm using Javascript for a Windows gadget, I'm pretty sure I have a leak because when I leave the gadget on for awhile the Memory and Commit Size fields in Windows Task Manager increase by a sizeable amount (and seem to keep increasing).

Comment: that is not necessarily a problem. But I know nothing of javascript but you need a proper tool. I'd ask a new question with that as the focus. There will be tools available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [perfmon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305610). It can monitor memory usage metrics for a process and can export the results to a file.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all processes with some interesting numbers like working set, private bytes, CPU usage, ... you can enter on a command prompt simply:

wmic process

You can do this on a regular basis and then make some graph out of it. The text file is rather simple a fixed width column format which is easy to parse.

Yours,
  Alois Kraus